# Android app for Google TV showing 0 devices

Tags: android, google-tv

I have checked the other questions, I have made sure the apk is activated, the app does work on my Logitech Revue as it should, but it's not showing up in the Google TV Market Place and it's showing the "This application is available to over 0 devices." in my console. I'll attempt to include my adroidmanifest file. I've read through the Android and Google developer doc, but can't seem to figure out why Google TV devices aren't listed or why it's not in the marketplace for Google TV. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.flickstream.channels"
android:versionCode="5"
android:versionName="1.1" >
<supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    />
    <uses-feature android:name="com.google.tv" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="com.google.android.tv" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".FlickStreamActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Did you already activate the APK and ticked the TOS?

Comment: Yes both, it shows up in market online. but not for the google tv devices.
https://market.android.com/details?id=com.flickstream.channels#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDIxMiwiY29tLmZsaWNrc3RyZWFtLmNoYW5uZWxzIl0.

Comment: I was able to get 2 devices to be compatible, Asura and "unknown". I'm mostly interested in getting it for the Logitech Revue though.

Comment: I think you need a "android:xlargeScreens="true"" too.

Answer (score 1):

because you declare the use of GPS in your manifest, and google TV has none, you should also put in the manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false"/>
```

(some ad networks use location services so you still want to keep it in your Manifest)

This was the solution for our Country Music RADIO app.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have all the right tags in your manifest. For my app it says it is available on 2 devices (internet tv and unknown). For my app it took more than a day for it to appear in the Market app section on Google TV, even though it was visible on the web market immediately. I could do a search for my app and find it on Google TV. I just searched yours and it finds the app but does not show in the Entertainment section when you browse the market.

Another trigger for getting it to appear might be if the app gets installed on a Google TV device or if somebody gives a rating.

Answer (score 0):

You have more *uses-feature* elements than you need, and the *supports-screens* element is unnecessary.

Try just the following for your *uses-feature* section:

```
<uses-feature android:name="com.google.android.tv" android:required="true"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had removed supports-screens tag from my app manifest and it showed up on Google TV.

I do not think there is any "com.google.tv" package. I believe you have the correct "com.google.android.tv" in the 2nd line. Here is Google TV manifest guidelines -
https://developers.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_androidmanifest

Try removing the following lines from your manifest.

```
<supports-screens
android:largeScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:smallScreens="false"
android:resizeable="true"
android:anyDensity="true"
/>
<uses-feature android:name="com.google.tv" android:required="true"/>
```